# Discord.Js: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')

Tags: discord.js, typeerror

my code is fine and everything is fine but i get an error.

My code:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
  client.user.setPresence({ activities: [{ name: 'Discord' }], status: 'idle' });
});

client.login(process.env.token);
```

The error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/discordjs-bot/index.js:5:47)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
```

**Any help?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In discord.js v14, the `Intents` import does not exist. You instead, need to use `GatewayIntentBits` when declaring the intents in the client. An example would be something like this:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        // ...
    ]
})
```

Comment: We should not answer the same question again and again. You already have a post that answers this question, so you could just flag this as a duplicate instead with a link to your other answer.

Comment: Yeah sorry. I can do that from now :)

Comment: No worries. You can still flag the question, even if you answered it ;) If a post is closed as a duplicate, no one else can answer it and duplicates won't get deleted by [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) either :)